# Mobilefirst 7.1 - Idle session timeout for Session-independent mode

Tags: jndi, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

How do I configure idle session timeout when application is configured in Session-independent mode.

Answer (score 0):

The idle session time out can be configured using "serverSessionTimeout" JNDI property. You can see the list of available JNDI properties here:
[List of JNDI properties](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/r_JNDI_entries_for_production.html?lang=en)

Comment: What is the difference between serverSessionTimeout in JNDI vs worklight.properties? Are we expected to set up both?

Comment: Is your solution for session-independent mode only?

Comment: Ref: Is your solution for session-independent mode only ?serverSessionTimeout configuration is not used in session-independent mode per the provided URL.

Comment: Ref: What is the difference between serverSessionTimeout in JNDI vs worklight.properties? Are we expected to set up both?
To my understanding the difference is the scope of effectiveness, where the former affects the server wide configuration and the later is set at module level i.e. .war file

Comment: Thanks Hamid. I get it now.

Comment: Can your please also help me with this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001644/mobilefirst7-1-idle-session-time-not-working-for-session-dependent-mode

Comment: As per my client requirement they want user session to be end in 10 Minutes. So I guess I have to set up the Application as Session dependent mode. When I implement it as per given in documentation it does not work for me. Please help me to know if I am doing any thing wrong. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001644/mobilefirst7-1-idle-session-time-not-working-for-session-dependent-mode